# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'string') with react joi-browser package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, web-frontend, joi

I have a problem with validating a form in react.
I have a register form in my react beginner project as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import Form from "./common/form";
import { Joi } from "joi-browser";
import * as userService from "../services/userService";
class RegisterForm extends Form {
  state = {
    data: { username: "", password: "", name: "" },
    errors: {}
  };
  schema = {
    username: Joi.string().required().email().label("Username"),
    password: Joi.string().required().min(5).max(15).label("Password"),
    name: Joi.string().required().label("Name")
  };

  doSubmit = async () => {
    await userService.registerUser(this.state.data);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {this.renderInput("username", "Username", "email")}
          {this.renderInput("password", "Password", "password")}
          {this.renderInput("name", "Name")}
          {this.renderButton("Register")}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RegisterForm;
```

as you can see i am using joi-browser package for validating my inputs but on the front i have the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'string') new
> RegisterForm E:/computer/Web/React,js/06 - Routing (00h53m)/1-
> Resources/Resources/Section 6-
> Routing/start/vidly/src/components/registerForm.jsx:11 8 | errors: {}
> 9 | }; 10 | schema = {
>
> > 11 | username: Joi.string().required().email().label('Username'), 12 | password: Joi.string().required().min(5).max(15).label('Password'),
> > 13 | name: Joi.string().required().label("Name") 14 | };

please help me anyone

Comment: the error suggests that `Joi` is not defined

Comment: but i have the joi-browser install in my project

Comment: anyone help me please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the line

```
import { Joi } from "joi-browser";
```

to

```
import Joi from "joi-browser";
```

and that should solve the error.

Comment: this saves my time!